# Rails pretty print json using render

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a new Rails app and a JSON API for it. I'm using `render` for API response encoding like so

```
render json: @images,
       only: [:id, :size, :mime_type, :file_name, :created_at],
       methods: methods
```

The above is OK, however it would be nice if the response was pretty printed. Googling didn't help much because all results suggested `JSON.pretty_generate` which does not handle `only` and `methods`.

Is there a way to pretty print with `render`? Or is there another standard way to accomplish the above (I'd prefer not to write a custom solution mimicking `render` API)?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/rails/jbuilder this will help.

Comment: So basically I have to either enhance my models with `to_builder` or write a .jbuilder file repeating 90% of the model? I'm a beginner in ruby/rails and find it very confusing how to get things done easily

Comment: I haven't been working with json in that key, so it's all i know.

Comment: I wonder if defining an `as_json` method on the model and combining that with `pretty_generate` could work.